# dart:js error when calling promiseToFuture - NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'jsPromise.then'

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to await a custom global JavaScript function:

```
  var promise = js.context.callMethod('performAuthenticationInNewWindow', [uri.toString()]);
  print(promise);
  var qs = await promiseToFuture(promise);
```

Which prints the following:

```
[object Promise]
NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'jsPromise.then'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came across the same mistake. Given the name `dart:js_util` of the package which contains the function promiseToFuture(), I too thought the function should be used with a object obtained with `dart:js`, but is not so, and the sample in the [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-js_util/promiseToFuture.html) is actually very clear.

The javascript Promise object must be obtained using the `@JS()` annotation of `package:js`.
Example:

```
@JS()
library my_lib; //Not avoid the library annotation

import 'dart:js_util';
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS()
external performAuthenticationInNewWindow(String uri);

performAuth(uri) async {
   var promise = performAuthenticationInNewWindow(uri.toString());
   var qs = await promiseToFuture(promise);
   print(qs);
}
```

Note to avoid mistake:

if a function for the interop with Javascript require an object obtained with the `dart:js` package, the declared type is usally not `Object` but `JsObject` or subclasses. Instead, if the object must be obtained using the `@JS` annotation, the declared type is `Object`, if it doesn't exists an appropriate external declaration
(the runtimeType of the objects obtained with the @JS annotation is `NativeJavaScriptObject`, but there is no corresponding class exposed in the Dart Sdk).